# Icons folder in a React Project is ignore by default

Tags: reactjs, icons, visual-studio-code

I am working on converting my react project into an npm-package. I am using the visual studio code editor Version 1.30.2 (1.30.2). My directory structure looks like this:

```
project
 - src
  - components
   - icons
     icons1.js
     icons2.js
```

However, my icon folder is being ignored and showing up as grey. Any file like icons1.js etc has the same property. I don't have the folder in my .gitignore either.

In addition, git doesn't detect the changes of adding the icons folder or files in it. If I rename the folder to something else it works. Renaming is only the last resort and I really want to understand what is going on.

How should I go about handling this issue?

Comment: Can you upload your gitignore file?

Comment: It mainly has:

build
node_modules